# Matching regexp term

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a regexp in google analytics goals for my dynamic cms pages.

I'm trying to create a funnel in order to determine the relationship between my category pages and my detail pages.

My Category pages are looking like this:

http://www.url.com/subcategories/flying_boards.html
http://www.url.com/subcategories/cheap_computers.html

What I put for the subcategory page is this: /subcategories/..html (not working).

My product pages are looking like:

http://www.url.com/veru-nice-computer-p-45854.html
http://www.url.com/amazing-pentium-4-laptop-p-58654.html

And what I put for this page as the regexp term is: /-p-..html (also not working).

I tried to search for answer but there is no way to check if what I think will be working is actually working before it goes live (and i'm loosing precious time...)

I Think its easy answer for some of the folks here And I'll really appreciate your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with regex : some characters are "reserved".
For example, the . mean "all possible character"

So, in /subcategories/..html you search all url in folder  subcategories and with a name file componed of 2 characters and ending with html.

I make some test in google analytics (it seems a little different of php or ruby regex), and I think you can just test with : /subcategories/
It will show you all url from this folder.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you answer, What abut the product page, you have any suggestion?